# How I can remove this freewheel (without "destroying" it)?

Tags: freewheel, single-speed

How I can remove this freewheel (without "destructing" it) ?

By "destructive removal" I mean this:

https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/freewheel-destructive-removal

[image: g]

P.S.

I found this tool:
[unior tools](https://youtu.be/nu-5aPLZ9pY?t=46)

But it seems to me to be overpriced (95$),

### UPDATE:

I found some indian tool online, which I assume should be much cheaper.
But I didn't find meanwhile, from where I can buy it online.

[link to video](https://youtu.be/WuhpOC4MYNw?list=LL56ilyayJ0-qtI613-uDVhQ&t=27)

[link to shop](https://www.cyclehandtools.com/products)

[image]

Comment: For a shop-quality tool and what it's designed to do, that price doesn't surprise me. For home use where you'll probably only use it once or twice, yeah that's a lot. If it were me, I would definitely destroy the freewheel and get something with proper removal notches.

Comment: Based on the brand name, its going to be a cheap and nasty freewheel that isn't worth saving anyway.  I've cut one off with a grinder in the past, which was a lot of fun.

Comment: You could remove the outer race and see if there's anything underneath to grab on to.

Comment: @Criggie How do you even comment deleted answers? Or why? I deleted and edited it for obvious reasons. I do know it is visoble for >10k  and mods but I do not get why should they be taken into any consideration. Not even the post author can comment a deleted post. If you want to inform me that I was wrong - yes, I was, just barely did not manage to edit the post in tje grace period. It happens, I am human, but I did delete the answer.

Comment: @VladimirF sorry I had the window open from earlier and just hadn't refreshed the page

Comment: @michaelD  Another option is to take the wheel into your LBS and get them to use their version of the expensive tool.  It might be a few dollars, or if you're a regular customer they might just bang it through if you make it easy by cleaning it all and taking in just the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Take the wheel to a bike shop. With the tool, its only a 5 minute job.

Comment: You're right, but that same answer could apply to almost every question here.  OP wants to remove the freewheel themselves.

Comment: I asked the bike shop, they told, that what they do is they openig it with hammer and kand of screw driver ....

Answer (score 0):

If you were almost willing to spend $95 on a tool for that, maybe consider one of [these](http://www.whiteind.com/wifreewheel). you will have invested wisely, and you can use [this thing](https://www.parktool.com/product/freewheel-remover-fr-6?category=Cassette%20%26%20Freewheel) along with your trusty chain whip and a standard adjustable wrench to remove it.

Comment: Sorry - check OP's photo and it shows there are no suitable notches or splines for that tool to fit.  The only interface seems to be those two notches at 10 and 4 o'clock of the innermost ring.